# How to build conditional eloquent query with data which comes from database

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create conditional query with data which comes from database. Now im using query and filtering method but i wonder is there any method to build query for this?

Example:
I have a table which exists 2 columns -> user_id and view_preference
if view_preference is 0 i want to select all records. But if its 1 i just want to select only matching user_id rows.

Current Working Code:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this then.

```sql
WHERE view_preference = 0
OR (
    view_preference = 1
    AND (
        owner_id = ?
        OR supervisor_id = ?
    )
)
```

Appending this to your query builder (before calling `get()`) should give you the results you want.

```php
->where('view_preference', 0)
->orWhere(function ($or) use ($request) {
    $or->where('view_preference', 1)
       ->where(function ($and) use ($request) {
           $and->where('owner_id', $request->user()->id)
               ->orWhere('supervisor_id', $request->user()->id);
       });
})
```